# Relative imports in Python Flask don't seem to work

Tags: python, flask, import, python-import, valueerror

I have the following directory structure for my Flask project

```
├── API
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── controllers.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── test
│       ├── first_test.py
│       
├── config.py
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── setup.py
```

My `setup.py` looks like following:

```
from setuptools import setup

    setup(
        name='project_name',
        packages=['API'],
        include_package_data=True
    )
```

I'm concerned about how can I import my `models` and `app (__init__)` into my test files (`first_test.py`).

So, far I have tried

```
from project_name.API import app

gives from project_name.API import app
E   ImportError: No module named project_name.API

from ..API import app
from ..API import app
E   ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

and

```
from .. import app
from .. import app
E   ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I can't figure out how to import the files. Also, I running the test files with `py.test API/test/first_test.py`

Comment: I think that good way is to download some of the flask skeletons on the github. I prefer "Flask-Skeleton" by RealPython. Everything is working there and you can easily find out how to correctly do it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a `setup.py` file under the root directory of the project.

Then, you can install your app using pip

```
pip install --editable .
```

By this way, you can import your application from the first_test.py file.

```
from API import app
```

Of course, the last import statement depends on where the app object stays.

For more information see the minitwit example in flask repo.

[minitwit](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/minitwit)

Hope, it helps.